# Formula to find point of value on logarithmic scale

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Suppose you have a logarithmic scale. The only thing we know about this scale is that it starts at $1$ and goes up by a factor of $n$ each step. For example, say $n = 3\%$:

```
0:    1.0000
1:    1.0300
2:    1.0609
3:    1.0927
4:    1.1255
....
98:  18.1154
99:  18.6589
100: 19.2186
...etc...
```

Now, given any random number above 1, I'd like to work out the position and value on the scale that this number relates to (eg first value equal to or greater than). Is there a formula to help me do this?

Thanks (ps not sure how to tag this question as not particularly mathematical)

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "the position and value on the scale that this number relates to". Do you mean someone gives you the value on the left and you calculate the value on the right, or the other way around? What exactly does "first value equal to or greater than" mean? What work have you done on this problem so far, and just where are you stuck?

Comment: I meant when given any random number, anything above 1, I want to find it's position on the scale. Answer below has helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the $s$th step, the value in the second column is $1.03^s$. Taking logarithms and rearranging gives that quantity is equal to $V$ when $s$ is $\frac{\log V}{\log 1.03}$. Since this quantity increases with $V$ and we're looking for the smallest integer $s$ for which $1.03^s$ is at least $V$, we simply need to round this quantity up to the nearest greater integer, and we can denote this rounded figure by
$$\left\lceil \frac{\log V}{\log 1.03} \right\rceil .$$
By the same reasoning, for some general growth ("interest") rate $r > 0$ (expressed as a decimal),
$$\left\lceil \frac{\log V}{\log (1 + r)} \right\rceil .$$